# How to have SBT skip cross compile for a given sub-project?

Tags: sbt

I've run into a couple related cases with SBT that have me stumped. Is there a way to tell SBT to skip a sub project entirely for certain scala versions when you're cross compiling?

Here are two examples where this would be useful.

1) A build with three projects A, B, and C. Both A and B are scala projects, and have 'scalaVersions ++= Seq("2.11.2", "2.10.4") in their settings. Project C is a pure-Java artifact, and thus I've excluded the Scala libraries from it's dependencies. I'd like A and B to depend on C, but ideally I'd only like to build C just once. If I use the default behavior and do "+publish" from the root aggregator project, I get two copies of C-1.0.0.jar produced, and SBT attempts to publish it twice, which is of course a no-no for a maven repository.

2) A build with multiple scala projects, but where one project should only build against a single Scala version. I've tried defining 'scalaVersions' in the settings for this project to hold only one version where the other projects have two, but again "+publish" from a root aggregator seems to ignore this and still compiles it twice, with the second time failing because it's dependencies aren't available for that Scala version. This project is a leaf node in the dependency graph, so it's a perfectly fine thing to want to do logically.

For case #2, I've thought of setting the source dirs for the 'bad' scala version to /dev/null or something similar, but that still actually runs the build and produces an empty artifact. I know I could probably go in and find all of the relevant keys and do something like

```
publishArtifact := if(scalaBinaryVersion.value == "2.10") false else publishArtifact.value
```

and then hunt down all of the other related settings/tasks (compile, compile in Test, test in Test, packageBin, etc) but that seems pretty hack-ish. Is there a 'skip' setting somewhere?

Answer (score 5):

I wrote [sbt-doge](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-doge) to address task aggregation across subprojects respecting their crossScalaVersions. For Java projects you might need a dummy `crossScalaVersion` entry.

Comment: This looks extremely useful, but I'm frankly leery of adding "so much test" and such to my build :-/

Comment: And I totally missed the "sensible" alternative in 0.1.4. My apologies, sir! This works like a charm!

Comment: @Tomer what tests and "sensible alternative" are you referring to?

Comment: @matt The doge-like syntax, and the "politically correct" alternative :-)

Comment: Can we be less consistently vague here @TomerGabel? :)

Comment: The "CrossPerProjectPlugin" offers the same functionality with sane syntax. Look up the sbt-doge project page for details.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin `sbt-doge` can be used to specify a `crossScalaVersion` setting in each subproject.

First, add the line `addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-doge" % "0.1.5")` to your `projects/plugins.sbt`.

To avoid the ridiculous doge syntax ("such compile", really?) you need to `enablePlugins(CrossPerProjectPlugin)` in your root project. With this, you can add a plus sign before your sbt commands, and they will honor the cross build settings. Just like this: `+ compile`.